# how can use multiClassSummary() function provide precision metric?

Tags: r, r-caret, confusion-matrix

The current multiClassSummary() function in R provides performance parameters without precision, example as following:

Example:

```
predicted <-  matrix(rnorm(50), ncol = 5)
observed <- rnorm(10)
apply(predicted, 2, postResample, obs = observed)
classes <- c("class1", "class2")
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(obs =  factor(sample(classes, 50, replace = TRUE)),
              pred = factor(sample(classes, 50, replace = TRUE)),
              class1 = runif(50), class2 = runif(50))
multiClassSummary(dat,lev=classes)
```

Results:

```
          logLoss               AUC          Accuracy             Kappa 
        0.6119378         0.4780844         0.6000000         0.1638796 
               F1       Sensitivity       Specificity    Pos_Pred_Value 
        0.6774194         0.7500000         0.4090909         0.6176471 
   Neg_Pred_Value    Detection_Rate Balanced_Accuracy 
        0.5625000         0.4200000         0.5795455
```

Is there a way to provide precision?

**Is it correct to take *Pos_Pred_Value* as the precision for class1 and *Neg_Pre_Value* as the precision of class2?**

Comment: If I run your code I also get precision and recall and some more variables. Check which version of caret you are using, I have 6.0-79.

Comment: @phiver, mine is 6.0-98. Did you get the precision same as PPV value? Could you please share your output here?

Comment: See the [news file](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/news.html). These were added in 6.0-77. Can you run `sessionInfo()` to verify?

Comment: when running sessionInfo(), it shows caret_6.0-78.

Comment: @phiver, yes, you're right. I runed the code in different systems and previously reported wrong information. For caret version 6.0-79, it reports precision, for 6.0-76, it doesn't. The code example is using 6.0-76. Do you want to submit your answer? I think it's correct.